# reading LIDC-IDRI dataset in its directory system?

Tags: python-3.x, pydicom

I am working on a project using LIDC-IDRI dataset that contains lung CT images which is a DICOM file (.dcm), the data is organized in folders, each folder has images for one scan, for clarification, I will give an example of first three scan folder system and the others follow the same principle(the images are in the last folder for each scan)

```
first scan:  LIDC-IDRI\LIDC-IDRI-0001\01-01-2000-30178\3000566-03192
second scan: LIDC-IDRI\LIDC-IDRI-0002\01-01-2000-98329\3000522-04919
third scan:  LIDC-IDRI\LIDC-IDRI-0003\01-01-2000-94866\3000611-03264
```

my question is, how to read the images inside this folder system? I mean not only one folder but all folders? I used the code below for reading images

```
import numpy as np
import pydicom
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_path = 'E:/LIDC-IDRI/'
patients_data = os.listdir(data_path)
patients_data.sort()

def load_scan(path):
    slices = [pydicom.read_file(path + '/' + s) for s in os.listdir(path)]

    return slices

full_path = load_scan(data_path + patients_data[0])
```

when i run it it gives me this error:

[image]

but when I change the folder system like below:(remove the last two folder for each scan):

```
first scan:  LIDC-IDRI\LIDC-IDRI-0001\
second scan: LIDC-IDRI\LIDC-IDRI-0002\
third scan:  LIDC-IDRI\LIDC-IDRI-0003\
```

it works without any error, can anyone tell me how to solve this please?

Answer (score 2):

Your first scan is 
`LIDC-IDRI\LIDC-IDRI-0001\01-01-2000-30178\3000566-03192`

The permission denied error is for file:
`e:/LIDC-IDRI/LIDC-IDRI-0001/01-01-2000-30178`

Note the `01-01-2000-30178` is a directory along the path to the first scan file. Permission is denied because the OS cannot read a directory like it can a normal file. You will need to modify the code to exclude directories, or to check for them and descend into them.

You could capture all filenames (but not directory names) in the whole tree with code like this:

```
import os.path
all_filenames = []
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(data_path):
    all_filenames += [os.path.join(dirpath, filename) for filename in filenames]
all_filenames.sort()
```

and then read them all with

```
slices = [pydicom.read_file(filename) for filename in all_filenames]
```